# what does "postsuper -d ALL" do on the filesystem?

Tags: files, email, postfix

```
postsuper -d ALL
```

will delete all mails that are still in the postqueue without sending them again.

But what exactly is happening on the filesystem when you call this command?

I have a snapshot of a mail-system with postfix. Now I want to run the snapshot but do not want to send out remaining mails from the postqueue.

I would like to manually empty the postqueue in the locally mounted VM-image before I start it as a running server. The easiest way would be just to delete all files in the postqueue, so what does `postsuper -d ALL` do exactly?

---

Update:
A more complex solution would be to chroot into the mounted system:

```
mkdir /media/tmp/
mount /dev/vg0/vm01.tmp-disk-snapshot /media/tmp/
mount -t proc none /media/tmp/proc
mount --bind /dev /media/tmp/dev
mount -t sysfs sysfs /media/tmp/sys
chroot /media/tmp/ /bin/bash
```

Empty the postqueue so no mails are sent from your test VM and exit

```
postsuper -d ALL
exit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR The `postsuper -d ALL` command deletes all the queued message files, in postfix queueing directories under `/var/spool/postfix/`.

Long answer:

As an example, having in the postfix queue 3 messages:

```
-Queue ID-  --Size-- ----Arrival Time---- -Sender/Recipient-------
8EDC660C92*     400 Sun May 10 13:42:22  root@debian.localdomain
                                         teste@sapo.pt

7334B60C89      395 Sun May 10 13:37:59  root@debian.localdomain
        (connect to mx.ptmail.sapo.pt[212.55.154.36]:25: Connection timed out)
                                         rui@sapo.pt

4BD3A60C8D      407 Sun May 10 13:38:18  root@debian.localdomain
(connect to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.28.26]:25: Connection timed out)
                                         filipe@gmail.com

-- 1 Kbytes in 3 Requests.
```

Monitoring `sudo postsuper -d ALL`, for deleted files:

```
30305 13:42:28.160381720 0 postsuper (1091) < unlink res=0 path=defer/7/7334B60C89(/var/spool/postfix/defer/7/7334B60C89) 
30329 13:42:28.160423699 0 postsuper (1091) < unlink res=0 path=defer/4/4BD3A60C8D(/var/spool/postfix/defer/4/4BD3A60C8D) 
30379 13:42:28.160481785 0 postsuper (1091) < unlink res=0 path=active/8EDC660C92(/var/spool/postfix/active/8EDC660C92) 
30419 13:42:28.160537670 0 postsuper (1091) < unlink res=0 path=deferred/7/7334B60C89(/var/spool/postfix/deferred/7/7334B60C89) 
30443 13:42:28.160574946 0 postsuper (1091) < unlink res=0 path=deferred/4/4BD3A60C8D(/var/spool/postfix/deferred/4/4BD3A60C8D)
```

Actually, just found out in the `postsuper` source code, the option -v (verbose), shows the file operations.

So, running `postfix -vd ALL`, for the above queue(s), has as output:

```
postsuper: name_mask: all
postsuper: inet_addr_local: configured 2 IPv4 addresses
postsuper: queue: defer
postsuper: removed file defer/7/7334B60C89
postsuper: removed file defer/4/4BD3A60C8D
postsuper: queue: bounce
postsuper: queue: maildrop
postsuper: queue: incoming
postsuper: queue: active
postsuper: removed file active/8EDC660C92
postsuper: queue: deferred
postsuper: removed file deferred/7/7334B60C89
postsuper: removed file deferred/4/4BD3A60C8D
postsuper: queue: hold
postsuper: queue: flush
```

In practice, monitoring visited directories by the command, and in what concerns the filesystem, a `postfix -d ALL` is equivalent to:

```
sudo find /var/spool/postfix/{defer,bounce,maildrop,incoming,active,deferred,hold,flush} -type f -exec rm {} \;
```

This last command, applied to your example case of a mounted file system, would be:

```
sudo find /media/tmp/var/spool/postfix/{defer,bounce,maildrop,incoming,active,deferred,hold,flush} -type f -exec rm {} \;
```

Nevertheless, `postsuper -d ALL` operates directly in directories and files, i.e in the filesystem - it does not need the `postfix`service to be up and running for clearing the queue(s). One alternative to deleting files directly, is booting the server in single mode and/or with the postfix service not running, and letting `postsuper -d ALL` do its job.

PS The find command is "unnecessarily" complicated having to enumerate all the queuing directories, due to `/var/spool/postfix` being setup as a chroot (at least in Debian), and having binary/library/dev/configuration files under that subtree area.